# UIReferenceLibraryViewController causing crash

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

I am hoping someone can help with with a bug I have introduced somewhere in my code. Things were working fine until I tried to clean old commented code out and must have deleted something.

It is a Cocos2d application. It is crashing whenever the initWithTerm method of UIReferenceLibraryViewController is being called.

```
reference = [[UIReferenceLibraryViewController alloc] initWithTerm:[[cell viewWithTag:1] text]];
```

This worked fine in the past. Now it is crashing

```
CoreFoundation`CFRelease:
0x24633b0:  pushl  %ebp
0x24633b1:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x24633b3:  pushl  %ebx
0x24633b4:  pushl  %edi
0x24633b5:  pushl  %esi
0x24633b6:  subl   $76, %esp
0x24633b9:  calll  0x24633be                 ; CFRelease + 14
0x24633be:  popl   %ebx
0x24633bf:  movl   %ebx, -32(%ebp)
0x24633c2:  movl   8(%ebp), %edi
0x24633c5:  testl  %edi, %edi
0x24633c7:  jne    0x24633df                 ; CFRelease + 47
0x24633c9:  int3   
0x24633ca:  calll  0x25baa00                 ; symbol stub for: getpid
0x24633cf:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x24633d2:  movl   $9, 4(%esp)
```

At this line,
    0x24633ca:  calll  0x25baa00
I am getting EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPR, subcode=0x0)

In the debug navigator, I see the following

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I have been experimenting further with this and have discovered that I get the same crash regardless of where I call 'UIReferenceLibraryViewController' from. For example, 'UIReferenceLibraryViewController *x = [[UIReferenceLibraryViewController alloc] initWithTerm:@"test"];' crashes the same way no matter where I included in my application.

Comment: I have resolved my problem for now. Previously, I had performed a 'Clean', restarted Xcode, rebooted my machine to see whether the issue would resolve. It had not resolved after these steps. Then without taking any additional measures, the issue resolved itself. It is running fine again in the simulator and on a device. Not sure what was going on here but I am back up and running. By the way, in order to improve my XCode debugging skills, I am following this excellent tutorial at http://maniacdev.com/2012/03/tutorial-objective-c-debugging-basics-with-xcode-4/